# How to move up ID in autoincrement column Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, identity-column

Now the highest ID in ID column is 192409. I need Oracle to start adding new values ​​from number 192734 (I want to values between 192409 and 192734 will be empty).
How can I do this?

This is how this column is configured

```
("ID" NUMBER(38,0) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY 
MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 
INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 125 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOT NULL ENABLE)
```

I tried to do update on last ID, but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter table, apparently.

Sample table and data:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id   number generated by default on null as identity,
  3     name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (name) values ('Foot');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot
```

Modify next value of the identity column:

```
SQL> alter table test modify id generated by default on null as identity (start with 192734);

Table altered.
```

Some more testing:

```
SQL> insert into test (name) values ('David');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot
    192734 David           --> here it is

SQL>
```

Comment: perfectly work. Thank you!